# Unwanted Expect 100 continue sent with POST request

Tags: visual-studio, web-testing

My web performance test is sending an `Expect: 100 continue` headers on POST requests. For some pages the web site being tested is returning a `417 Expectation Failed` with the message `The expectation given in the Expect request-header field could not be met by this server`.

How can I suppress this one header field from being sent by my web test?

(Using Visual Studio 2015.)

Answer (score 0):

Can remove all `Expect` headers by using the following plugin. The code was based on [this Microsoft page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0dd02db-bc2b-454a-be7f-4f6023e5eb98/expect-100continue-header-is-being-added-to-webtest?forum=vstswebtest).

```
public class CancelExpect100Continue : WebTestPlugin
{
    public override void PreWebTest(object sender, PreWebTestEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    }
}
```

Details of the `Expect100Continue` field and when `Expect` headers are added to requests can be found in [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.expect100continue(v=vs.110).aspx).